# 【Flutter】Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, photoview

This is a Flutter project.
I have tried the following

1. $Flutter clean
2. $Flutter pub cache repair
3. photo_view: ^0.14.0
4. use the version of document_scanner_flutter in the pull request

However, none of these had any effect.

- Error message

```
Error (Xcode):
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_view-0.12.0/lib/src/core/photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:89:
38: Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'.


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

- pubspec.yaml

```
name: xxxx
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  jiffy: ^6.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+1
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  document_scanner_flutter: ^0.2.7
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl: 5.1.0-LTS
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  media_scanner: ^2.1.0
  share_plus: ^4.5.3
  sqflite: ^2.2.6
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.4.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.0
  package_info_plus: ^3.1.0
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.7.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

- Flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.10.2 on channel stable at /Users/t/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9cd3d0d9ff (4 weeks ago), 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
    • Engine revision 90fa3ae28f
    • Dart version 3.0.2
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/t/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue. Don't really know the reason, but, I was able to fix this by going to the file ***photo_view_gesture_detector.dart*** and removing ***kind*** field from super constructor. Change `super(debugOwner: debugOwner, kind: kind)` to `super(debugOwner: debugOwner)`

Comment: IN gallery_view: ^1.0.0+1 version is not working, we will get `photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:106:29: Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error you can clone this GitHub package instead of pub dev package

```
  document_scanner_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/dattm2593/document_scanner_flutter.git
      ref: 6ead0cf989e3d3567c785ab2774737a4f8e7bcd7
```